# cannot install twrp on android nexus 6p

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, twrp, flashtool, nexus-6p

so i want to root my phone by first installing a custom recovery (twrp) following instructions [here](https://twrp.me/devices/huaweinexus6p.html).. but as soon as i run this command

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

i get this:

```
target reported max download size of 494927872 bytes
sending 'recovery' (16904 KB)...
OKAY [  0.396s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: device is locked. Cannot flash images)
finished. total time: 0.416s
```

i turned on the phone and enabled OEM unlocking.. but i still get the above error.. ideas?

Comment: Have you actually unlocked your bootloader? You need to enable the setting within Android and also unlock it. **Note** unlocking the bootloader wipes the device so all user data will be lost.

Comment: [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928) is the coolest guide from Heisenberg for Nexus 6P. Follow it to get the things sorted out including bootloader unlocking, recovery flashing and rooting.